# How to perform a unit test in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, python-unittest

I have a program and I want to test my code.
This is [one](https://github.com/NischayaSharma/python-codes/blob/master/src/fileManipulation/Employee.py) and this is the [other](https://github.com/NischayaSharma/python-codes/blob/master/src/fileManipulation/FileHandeling.py). I want to test the Employee.py one with the help of unit test framework but have got no idea from where to start. I tried with basic terminal by entering a few values and getting results but I was curious if this would hold good even for a large amount of data. So how do I go forward with it? I also heard of pytest but the forums said it works better with Django and stuff so I was sticking to unittest

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: Had I understood that I would never had asked the question here

Comment: So you need a unittest tutorial? [There are plenty of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+unittest+tutorial). Also, The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python has [a good overview of testing tools with examples](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/tests/).

Comment: Thanks, Will check it out.